# How does `std::shared_ptr` cyclic dependency cause a problem

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers

I found several related questions, but I couldn't find an explanation regarding "how" this happens.

I have the following code, which is one step behind the version that can create a cyclic `shared_ptr` reference problem.
(Adding `b.other = a;` before return causes the problem)

For better clarification, I added comments on important lines to indicate the state of the program at that point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    explicit Foo(char i) : id{i} { cout << "Constructed " << id << endl; }
    ~Foo() { cout << "Destructed " << id << endl; }

    shared_ptr<Foo> other = {};
    char const id;
};

int main()
{
    auto const a = make_shared<Foo>('a'); // a_use_count = 1, b_use_count = 0
    auto const b = make_shared<Foo>('b'); // a_use_count = 1, b_use_count = 1

    a->other = b; // a_use_count = 1, b_use_count = 2

    return 0;     // What happens now? Following is my "expectation" (which is wrong !)
                  // 1. destruct b => a_use_count = 1, b_use_count = 1
                  // 2. destruct a (in following order)
                  //    2.1 destruct a.other => b_use_count = 0 => show "Destructed b"
                  //    2.2 destruct a       => a_use_count = 0 => show "Destructed a"
}
```

However, things do not happen as I expect. `a` and `b` gets destructed in the opposite order. I am seeing the following output.

```
Constructed a
Constructed b
Destructed a
Destructed b
```

What exactly happens when the program returns above?
(I hope understanding this will help understanding the cyclic dependency problem)

Comment: What's happening with the shown program isn't very complicated, however it is mostly unrelated to the underlying issues caused by cyclic dependencies, except in a very rudimentary way.

Comment: Is that Q specifically about C++11?

Comment: @curiousguy It's about C++11 and later because `std::shared_ptr` was not available before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The destructor body is executed *before* the members are destroyed (the reverse of the constructor behavior.)

Therefore when `a` in `main` is destructed, the shared pointer count of `a` reaches zero *first*, then the destructor of the managed `Foo` is called, *first* prining the message `Destructed a`, and *then* `other` is destroyed, which causes `Destructed b` to be printed in the destructor of its managed `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked the obvious. I will think again whether I understand the cyclic dependency problem and either accept your answer or update my question.

Comment: @Sumudu If you want to demonstrate the cyclic dependency problem with `shared_ptr`, then you need to actually make the dependency cyclic, by e.g. adding `b->other = a`. If you follow the same analysis in that case, you will see that none of the destructors will execute, indication for a memory leak.